# How to increase the border/frame width for ListBox in win32

Tags: winapi, listbox

In win32 appliction,how to increase the listbox border/frame width?

I want to get listbox similar to given below.
[image: Listbox Image]

I am using below to create listbox

```
CRect p(7, 35, 300, 200);

DWORD  m_ListStyle =WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|LBS_NOTIFY|WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|WS_BORDER;

m_ListStyle ^= LBS_SORT;

m_ctrlListBox.Create(m_ListStyle , p, this,IDC_LIST);

m_ctrlListBox.SetFont(GetParent()->GetFont());
```

Comment: What you are seeing there is most likely a listbox with a standard frame, that has a top-level parent window without the `WS_CAPTION` style. The "extended" frame comes from this parent window.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to increase the border size and not just the overall control size (which is where the standard control will put any window area not occupied by the border) you will need to subclass the control and call DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea, you will also have to paint that border area (in response to WM_NCPAINT) and handle any mouse clicks in that area (WM_NCHITTEST and possibly other actions I'm not thinking of.

Comment: `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` is for top-level windows, not for child windows. For child windows, `WM_NCCALCSIZE` should be handled.